# App keeps forgetting sharedpreferences on restart

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I don't know what to do with it any more

Seems to be working fine with android 3.0 and higher, but on android 2.3.3 every time I launch the application it is asking for the username/password again.

I'm using the shared preferences.

Here is how I save preferences:

```
        SharedPreferences preferences = MyApplication.getAppContext().getSharedPreferences("athopbalance", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString("username", username).commit();
        editor.putString("password", password).commit();
```

And here is how I read them:

```
    SharedPreferences preferences = MyApplication.getAppContext().getSharedPreferences("athopbalance", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String username = preferences.getString("username", "");
    String password = preferences.getString("password", "");
```

I also tried to save preferences using this code:

```
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MyApplication.getAppContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString("username", username).commit();
        editor.putString("password", password).commit();
```

And the read them with this code:

```
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MyApplication.getAppContext());
    String username = preferences.getString("username", "");
    String password = preferences.getString("password", "");
```

But it doesn't work either.

The problem is before I restart the application I can see that they are still there. However as soon as I do the restart - I end up with getting "" (empty string) for username and "" for password.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what happened, but after I've restarted the emulator issue is gone.

Sorry to waste your time

Comment: Same issue here and it gone after restart just like yours. Really strange…

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private static MyApplication instance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate() called");
    }

    public MyApplication() {
        super();
        Log.d(TAG, "Constructor called");
        instance = this;
    }


    public static MyApplication getApplication() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new MyApplication();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
MyApplication.getApplication().getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

Comment: Your example doesn't save the `new MyApplication` into instance before returning so the caching never happens.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("YOUR_TAG", 0);
 String username = preferences.getString("username", "");
 String password = preferences.getString("password", "");


  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString("username", username).commit();
    editor.putString("password", password).commit();
```

where context is the context of your app:

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        context = this;
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your comment. I'm doing pretty the same in my first example, but I'm afraid it doesn't work

Comment: try with your activity  instead of MyApplication.

Comment: I was calling getApplicationContext()  instead of passing the context from the activity.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

1. Get shared preference value during the life-cycle of the activity.
2. Call `.clear` before `.commit`

See my answer:

[Android Persistent Checkable Menu in Custom Widget After Reboot Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36939380/android-persistent-checkable-menu-in-custom-widget-after-reboot-android)